# Address returned by alloc_pages are same if I use two alloc_pages for checking

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to analyse `alloc_pages()` functionality.
I know it returns the physical address of the first-page struct it is pointing to.
I would like to confirm with the below code.

```
struct page *page;
page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 0);
pr_info("physical address GFP_KERNEL - %p\n", page); 
page = alloc_pages(GFP_HIGHUSER, 2);
pr_info("physical address of GFP_High - %p\n", page);
```

As you can see I used `alloc_pages()` twice, but I got the same address returned. Shouldn't I get a different address?

I edited it from &page -> page in pr_info function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print value and address of pointer defined in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914298/print-value-and-address-of-pointer-defined-in-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should print out the value of `page` directly, not the address of `page`.

like below:

```
struct page *page;
page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 0);
pr_info("physical address GFP_KERNEL - %p\n", page);

page = alloc_pages(GFP_HIGHUSER, 2);
pr_info("physical address of GFP_High - %p\n", page);
```

#### Module full code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

struct page *page1;
struct page *page2;

static int __init test_alloc_pages_init(void)
{
    struct page *page;
    page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL, 0);
    pr_info("physical address GFP_KERNEL - %p\n", page);
    page1 = page;

    page = alloc_pages(GFP_HIGHUSER, 2);
    pr_info("physical address of GFP_High - %p\n", page);
    page2 = page;

    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_alloc_pages_exit(void)
{
    if (page1) {
        pr_info("free page1: %p\n", page1);
        __free_pages(page1, 0);
    }
    if (page2) {
        pr_info("free page2: %p\n", page2);
        __free_pages(page2, 2);
    }
    return;
}

module_init(test_alloc_pages_init);
module_exit(test_alloc_pages_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

dmesg info:

```
[117582.127432] physical address GFP_KERNEL - ffffea002e1cf2c0
[117582.127434] physical address of GFP_High - ffffea002e0ec500
[117584.214921] free page1: ffffea002e1cf2c0
[117584.214922] free page2: ffffea002e0ec500
```

Comment: thanks for correction, but i am getting same value even after modification. Could you please check for you is it working?

Comment: Can work, you use the module complete code(above) to try the results in your environment