# why the value of *p0 is having a different value every time in the compilation. here is the code for the the problem in c language .?

Tags: c, pointers

```
<#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    //type casting in pointers

    int a = 500; //value is assgned
    int *p;   //pointer p
    p = &a;   //stores the address in the pointer
    printf("p=%d\n*p=%d", p, *p);
    printf("\np+1=%d\n*(p+1)=%d", p + 1, *(p + 1));

    char *p0;
    p0 = (char *)p;
    printf("\n\np0=%d\n*p0=%d", p0, *p0);

    return 0;
}
```

I was exploring the pointers in the C language and found a problem in finding the value at the address of
the char pointer when I converted it from a integer pointer.

Tell me how it works and explain please

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior when trying to access `*(p + 1)`. Well, technically you are invoking it when printing pointer value with `%d` too

Comment: `%d` is not the correct format string for a pointer. Probably you've got 64 bit pointers and 32 bit ints, so you're getting the left-over parts of the pointer in the second %d, but it's all undefined behavior. But doesn't your compiler warn about this?

Comment: Please post some sample output you are seeing for a couple runs, and explain what you were _expecting_ to see, so we can know what we should be explaining to you.

Comment: `printf("p=%d\n*p=%d", p, *p);` -> `printf("p=%p\n*p=%d", (void*)p, *p);`

Comment: no my compiler does not give a warning in this case..

Comment: p=6487564
*p=500
p+1=6487568
*(p+1)=0

p0=6487564
*p0=-12

Comment: these are the output i am getting why *p0 is -12 pz explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To print a pointer use `%p` and cast the argument to `(void*)`.

Like

```
printf("p=%p\n*p=%d", (void*)p, *p);
```

2. Reading `p + 1`, i.e. doing `*(p + 1)`, is undefined behavior because `p + 1` doesn't point to an `int`. So don't do that!

In a comment OP asks:

> p=6487564 *p=500 p+1=6487568 *(p+1)=0 p0=6487564 *p0=-12
> these are the output i am getting why *p0 is -12 pz explain

The decimal value 500 is the same as the hexadecimal value 0x000001F4. On a little endian machine (with 32 bit `int`) this is stored like:

```
p -> F4 01 00 00
```

Then you assign `p0` the value of `p` so you have

```
p -> F4 01 00 00
     ^
     |
     p0
```

so `p0` points to 0xF4 (assuming 8 bit char).

On a machine with signed chars, the hex value 0xF4 is the decimal value -12 (i.e. signed 8 bit 2's complement representation).

**Conclusion** On a little endian machine with signed 8 bit chars the printed value will be `-12`.

If you change

```
char *p0;
p0 = (char *)p;
```

to

```
unsigned char *p0;
p0 = (unsigned char *)p;
```

then it will print 244. That may be easier to understand because 500 is 256 + 244 (or in hex: 0x1F4 = 0x100 + 0xF4).

Comment: I don't think casting the pointer to `void*` when printing it is really necessary.

Comment: @GabrielStaples It works on most systems without a cast but to be standard compliant, the cast is needed.

Comment: I see. [This en.cppreference.com documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for `printf()` says that the expected argument type is `void *`, as well. I never noticed that before, as I normally look at [this http://www.cplusplus.com/ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) instead.

Comment: @GabrielStaples IMO cppreference is much better than cplusplus. Anyway, the standard is the ultimate place to look. In the standards description of `%p` you'll find: "... The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a
pointer to void.. ..."

Comment: @Gabriel Staples if you think void* is not necessary then show a simple example of code

Comment: @vishalkumawat, `printf("p=%p\n*p=%d", p, *p);`, or: `printf("p=%lu\n*p=%d", (uint64_t)p, *p);`, or even better than the latter one of those two: `#include <inttypes.h>` then `printf("p=%" PRIu64 "\n*p=%d", (uint64_t)p, *p);`, or in hex: `printf("p=0x%" PRIX64 "\n*p=%d", (uint64_t)p, *p);`.

Comment: @Gabriel Staples tx

Comment: @vishalkumawat The only correct (i.e. standard compliant) way to print a pointer is to use `%p` and cast the argument using `(void*)`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32914514/4386427